# White fuzzy balls on jade plant roots

Tags: succulents, roots

[image]

My jade plant has these white fuzzy balls forming on its roots. Not sure if this is some type of mould or insect eggs?

I don't currently use any pesticides on my succulent... can anyone recommend how is best to get rid of these white balls?

This happened a few months ago and I cut away all the roots which seemed to have this stuff on them (was left with barely any roots) but they seem to have come back so it must not have gotten rid of whatever it was.

UPDATE: I have removed all the soil from the roots and sprayed them with isopropanol alcohol. Fingers crossed they stay clean[image: ![jade plant roots]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TJsN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is either a mold or an insect as you suspected. TBH, a simple treatment option (for either) would be to re-pot the plant with a new container and new soil. Try using sterilized soil this time. No need to cut back the roots just clean them off by hand. Just be thorough about removing the white larva/mold and the old dirt. In fact clean the whole plant thoroughly during the re-potting process, don't scrub it with anything abrasive just use your hands.

EDIT: Use clean water when cleaning!

Comment: Thanks for this! I've updated my post with a picture! Hopefully this will sort it

Comment: @user284408 I am assuming you either cleaned the alcohol off the plants or diluted the alcohol you sprayed considering I don't see any burning. Looks good, I am sure they will do fine now.

Comment: They look great now!

Answer (score 1):

That might be root mealie bugs. If they appear to be alive, quarantine this plant from all the others. Remove all the potting media and trim any dead roots.

You can spray with 70% isopropyl alcohol once you've removed all the bugs you can. There are many other treatment options, but alcohol is usually handy in the home.

Mealies are nasty and can spread unless you act quickly. Root mealies are difficult to detect because they are under the soil.

Good luck.

Comment: Thankyou, didn't seem to be alive when I reported but I used isopropanol alcohol to clean just incase. I've updated my post with a picture!

Answer (score 0):

Please examine the white stuff carefully and see if it is crystalline like salt. In a case where the plant has been given too much fertilizer in solution, as the root ball dries out if the concentration of salts in solution is high enough then the salts will come out of the solution and form crystals again.

Note that salts can accumulate over time since with each "feeding", as the plant dries only the water evaporates leaving the salt behind.

As a test, put some of the white material in a saucer and put it on a sunny window sill to dry out. If it goes to a salt like material that feels rough then it probably is not a fungus/insect material which will go more powdery.